# in xsl how do I get table of contents to have different formatting for different types of entries

Tags: xslt, docbook, tableofcontents, docbook-xsl

I have to format the table of contents of a docbook using xsl so that the entries for "top level" sections are bold and have a certain font and font size, but the entries for sect2 and sect3 aren't bold and have different fonts and font sizes. How do I do this?

E:
I keep trying to change it in

```
<xsl:template name="toc.line">
```

in autotoc.xsl but every time I try a variation of

```
<xsl:if test="self::sect1">
```

it never accepts it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what is the target format (e.g. HTML or PDF) you currently transform docbook to?

Comment: transforming from docbook to fo through xsl and then from fo to pdf.

Comment: I did that Spangen

Comment: Testing the element name in xsl:if is usually a sign of poor coding practice: switching on element name should usually be done by means of template rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: What does "it never accepts it" mean exactly? Do you get an error message? If so, which one exactly? Which version of Docbook do you use, which version of the stylesheets, which version of XSLT? It could be simply a namespace problem e.g. the input elements might be in the docbook namespace and of course in XSLT you then need to make sure you select or match based on the namespace so if you have e.g. `<sect1 xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">...</sect1>` then in XSLT 1 you need e.g. `<xsl:if test="self::d:sect1" xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">...</xsl:if>`.

Comment: Or in XSLT 2 you need to declare `xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` to be able to use `<xsl:if test="self::sect1">` to select a `sect1` element in that DocBook namespace.

Comment: sect1 is not a an element in the docbook they all just say section, sect1 should refer to the top level sections as opposed to sections within sections. I'm using xsl 1.78.1

Comment: I've gotten it to have different section headings based on the 'level' of the section. I'm docbook v 4.3